# C# Making the binary search code look and work better

Tags: c#

Could you give me some suggestions how I could optimise this code(By code looks, and speed maybe)

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        public static int BinarySearch(int[] array, int target)
        {
            int pointer = array.Length / 2;
            int ourLength = array.Length / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (array[pointer] == target) return pointer;
                else
                {
                    if (array[pointer] > target) pointer -= ourLength / 2;
                    else pointer += ourLength / 2;
                }
                ourLength /= 2;
                if (ourLength == 0) ourLength = 2;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Result = " + BinarySearch(new int[] { 1, 5, 23, 111 }, 111));
        }
    }
```

Code works, but I feel that it is a bit off ... That there is some way to do it without `ourLength`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why not simply use the [system provided version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=net-6.0#system-array-binarysearch-1(-0()-0))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternate option which may be a bit more readable.

```
public static int BinarySearch(int[] array, int target)
{
    int minPosition = 0;
    int maxPosition = array.Length - 1;
    int position = maxPosition / 2;
    
    while (maxPosition >= minPosition)
    {
        if (array[position] == target)
            return position;
        else if (array[position] < target)
            minPosition = position + 1;
        else if (array[position] > target)
            maxPosition = position - 1;
        
        position = (maxPosition + minPosition) / 2;
    }
    return -1;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Result = " + BinarySearch(new int[] { 1, 5, 23, 111 }, 111));
}
```